# Conditional subsetting of Seurat object

Tags: r, subset, seurat

I have a [Seurat](https://satijalab.org/seurat/index.html) object that I have run through [doubletFinder](https://github.com/chris-mcginnis-ucsf/DoubletFinder). I am trying to subset the  object based on cells being classified as a 'Singlet' under `seurat_object@meta.data[["DF.classifications_0.25_0.03_252"]]` and can achieve this by doing the following:

```
seurat_object <- subset(seurat_object, subset = DF.classifications_0.25_0.03_252 == 'Singlet') #this approach works
```

I would like to automate this process but the `_0.25_0.03_252` of `DF.classifications_0.25_0.03_252` is based on values that are calculated and will not be known in advance. I can figure out what it is by doing the following:

```
meta_data = colnames(seurat_object@meta.data)[grepl("DF.classification", colnames(seurat_object@meta.data))]
```

Where `meta_data = 'DF.classifications_0.25_0.03_252'` and is a character class.

However, when I try to do any of the following:

```
seurat_object <- subset(seurat_object, subset = meta_data == 'Singlet') #this approach does not recognize meta_data
seurat_object <- subset(seurat_object, subset = seurat_object@meta.data$meta_data == 'Singlet') #this approach does not work
seurat_object <- subset(seurat_object, subset = seurat_object@meta.data[[meta_data]] == 'Singlet') #this approach does not work
```

I get an error that states:

```
Error in FetchData(object = object, vars = unique(x = expr.char[vars.use]),  :   
  None of the requested variables were found: 
Calls: remove_doublets ... subset.Seurat -> WhichCells -> WhichCells.Seurat -> FetchData
Execution halted
```

I am at loss for how to perform conditional matching with the `meta_data` variable. Does anyone have an idea how I can automate the subset process? *Many thanks in advance*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked.

```
seurat_object = seurat_object[, seurat_object@meta.data[, meta_data] == "Singlet"]
```

But I especially don't get why this one did not work:

```
seurat_object <- subset(seurat_object, subset = seurat_object@meta.data[[meta_data]] == 'Singlet')
```

If anyone can tell me why the latter did not function I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

@cer :

> But I especially don't get why this one did not work:
> `seurat_object <- subset(seurat_object, subset = seurat_object@meta.data[[meta_data]] == 'Singlet')`

the name in double brackets should be in quotes [["meta_data"]] and should exist as column-name in the meta.data data.frame (at least as I saw in my own seurat obj)

Thanks for the reply anw!

Comment: (palm-face-impact)...@MariaK...where were you 3 months ago?! :) Thank you.